1-D subpixel barcode recognition
all.Recently, I met a problem called subpixel barcode recognition. When the image resolution is so low that the edges of bars and white spaces are blurred, therefore we can not recover the edge and recognize the barcode. I put the image sample here, can anybody give me a clue on how to solve the problem, thanks.
subpixel barcode image sample
I tried to compute the differentials but doesn't seem to work.

Even as human I cannot see the lines any more so reading the numbers below the barcode seams to be your best chance.

When compared to how fully perfect Code39 is supposed to look, you are clearly missing some lines that appear as a gray mass.  Code39 is a very dense code, and blurring it won't make it better.   Choose a different code.

Should use the signal-processing tag and remove subpixel.  I'd do the edit myself, but there's another pending edit in the way.  Also you probably meant image-processing, not image + processing.

This is a neat problem.  It looks possible to me, because over the whole image of the 1-D bar code, you have a lot of samples.
I would try a process like this:

Isolate the part of the image that contains the bar code, and put it on a matching background;
Take a 2D FFT, and use principal component analysis to extract the bar code major axis;
Resample in 1D by moving each pixel to its projection on that major axis.  Note that this is an irregular sampling.
Do a 1D least squares fit to a Fourier basis of sufficient resolution to represent the bar code.  This finds the best 1D representation of all those irregular samples.
Equalize the frequencies to match the expected spectrum of the bar code, which you can extract from analyzing randomly generated samples.  This is a "deconvolution" that aims to undo the blurring effect of the camera. If you actually have detailed information about your camera or can measure it, then you could get a more accurate estimate of the required equalization.
Inverse FFT to recover the 1-D bar code at higher resolution.


The case is uneasy because in addition to blur, there is severe noise.
After magnification, deskewing (manual) and denoising by vertical averaging, this is what you get:

The bar information is still present but bar thickness estimation will be difficult. The edges could be located as the inflection points in the profile, measured to subpixel accuracy, at the zero crossings of the derivative.


Thanks a lot for the above answers to all you guys in this community. As I've tried many times on this problem. I guess none of the above answers can solve this problem. Since the signal has degraded seriously so that we should find a way to reconstruct the signal first. I figure out that the information between different lines is redundant  and we should utilize multiple lines and do some type of interpolation for the super-resolution kind of reconstruction. Anyone who can give me some guildance will be very helpful. Thank you very much.
